# Simple node.js readline on the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, readline

I'd like to teach students how to program using JavaScript. I don't want to introduce new students to call-backs or any other complex program structure. Looking at Node.js the readline used for standard input uses a call-back. For simple input data, then do a calculation, I'd like a simple equivalent to an input like Python or other similar languages have:

```
width = input("Width? ")
height = input("Height? ")
area = width * height
print("Area is",area)
```

Is there some way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module `readline-sync`, (source can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/readline-sync), npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/readline-sync)) will do what you want, it looks like.

If you'd prefer to work at a lower level, it looks like it works by passing the `stdin` file descriptor (`stdin.fd`) to the synchronous `fs` methods.  For example:

```
fs.readSync(stdin.fd, buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is [sget](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sget) as well, a simpler and bit [saner](https://github.com/anseki/readline-sync/blob/master/lib/readline-sync.js) module I wrote that accomplishes what the OP is asking for.

```
var sget = require('./sget');

var width = sget('Width?'),
    height = sget('Height?'),
    area = width * height;

console.log('Area is', area);
```